# How to include stopping rule in function which iterates in R?

Tags: r, function, k-means

Suppose we have the following functions: one that calculates Euclidean distance, the other that calculates the k-means algorithm.

```
euclid <- function(points1, points2) {
  distanceMatrix <- matrix(NA, nrow=dim(points1)[1], ncol=dim(points2)[1])
  for(i in 1:nrow(points2)) {
    distanceMatrix[,i] <- sqrt(rowSums(t(t(points1)-points2[i,])^2))
  }
  distanceMatrix
}

K_means <- function(x, centers, distFun, nItter) {
  clusterHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  centerHistory <- vector(nItter, mode="list")
  
  for(i in 1:nItter) {
    distsToCenters <- distFun(x, centers)
    clusters <- apply(distsToCenters, 1, which.min)
    centers <- apply(x, 2, tapply, clusters, mean)
    # Saving history
    clusterHistory[[i]] <- clusters
    centerHistory[[i]] <- centers
  }
  
  list(clusters=clusterHistory, centers=centerHistory)
}

test=data # A data.frame
ktest=as.matrix(test) # Turn into a matrix
centers <- ktest[sample(nrow(ktest), 5),] # Sample some centers, 5 for example

res <- K_means(ktest, centers, euclid, 100) # 100 iterations
```

However, I'd like to include a rule within the `K_means` function which stops the algorithm when it converges. So in the above output for instance, the number of iterations is 100, but the results for many of those iterations will be the same. I.e. I'd like to use a stopping rule where the algorithm has converged (and hence, stop the function) whenever the cluster assignments don't change from one iteration to the next.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Something like `if (...) break`? Check `?check`

Comment: @ekoam, I think you meant to refer to `?break`.

Comment: Would either of you know how to implement that in the example code I have provided?